# Get images url from folder Filter only images from folder

Tags: php, jquery, slider, getfiles

I use the code suggested here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18316453

This is what I have now.

```
<?php
$dir = "sliders/slides";
$images = array();
if (is_dir($dir))
{
if ($dh = opendir($dir))
 {
  while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
  {
    if (!is_dir($dir.$file)) $images[] = $dir . '/' . $file;
  }
  closedir($dh);
 } 
}
echo json_encode($images);
?>
```

My result includes 2 extra items

```
sliders/slides/.
sliders/slides/..
```

which makes my slider having 2 extra blank slides

How can I filter the result to show only .jpg and .png files in order to remove `/.` and `/..` be included in the results

I'm trying to create sliders that gets images from a folder

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this inside the while :

```
if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && !is_dir($file) {
    $images[] = $dir . '/' . $file;
}
```

Comment: great!! will wait for a while before I accept. It seems I can't accept for now.